# Resize background image in div using css

Tags: html, css

Below css sets an individual background on two divs; the images repeat themselves if they do not fit into the div size.

How can I stretch the images using css to fit into space required by div ?

```
<style type="text/css">   
#contentMain {  
  margin-bottom: 5%; 
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background: url( /jQuery/mypage/img/background1.png )
}  
#page1 {    
  background: url( /jQuery/mypage/img/background2.png )  
} 
</style>
```

Comment: CSS3 comes with `background-size` however IE8 and less won't support it.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

## Answer

You have multiple options:

1. `background-size: 100% 100%;` - image gets stretched (aspect ratio may be preserved, depending on browser)
2. `background-size: contain;` - image is stretched without cutting it while  preserving aspect ratio
3. `background-size: cover;` - image is completely covering the element while  preserving aspect ratio (image can be cut off)

/edit: And now, there is even more: https://alligator.io/css/cropping-images-object-fit

### [Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/alp82/pen/wqPaNe?editors=1100)

## Update 2017: Preview

Here are screenshots for some browsers to show their differences.

### Chrome

[image: preview background types chrome]

---

### Firefox

[image: preview background types firefox]

---

### Edge

[image: preview background types edge]

---

### IE11

[image: preview background types ie11]

## Takeaway Message

### `background-size: 100% 100%;` produces the least predictable result.

## Resources

- https://alligator.io/css/cropping-images-object-fit

Comment: See http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/ and the more theoretical http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Comment: thank you, @Alp and @jao! this answer and comment really helped me instead of using ugly javascript to create a separate img element and then set the height and width before putting the img back into the div instead.

Answer (score 10):

i would recommend using this:

```
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image: url(your file location here);
  background-size:cover;(will only work with css3)
```

hope it helps :D

And if this doesnt support your needs just say it: 
i can make a jquery for multibrowser support.

Comment: A jQuery with multibrowser support would be perfect, thanks!

Comment: well i was lazy and have found a nice tutorial that will help you understand what your doing:

http://designshack.co.uk/?p=13616

Answer (score 4):

With the [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property in those browsers which support this very new feature of CSS.